# Transform vectory by non-static member function

Tags: c++, templates

Consider this template function:

```
template<class T, class F> inline
auto transform(const vector<T>& l, F func) -> vector<decltype(func(T{}))>
{
    vector<decltype(func(T{}))> out(l.size());
    std::transform(l.begin(), l.end(), out.begin(), func);
    return out;
}
```

This function can be called as

```
auto out = transform(intputVector, functor)
```

functor has to be either static member fuction or a global function.

Is there a way to modify the above code to work on non-static member functions as well?

```
struct Test {

    Test() {

        vector<int> vx = { 1, 2, 3 };
        auto vy1 = transform(vx, staticMemberFunc); // is fine
        auto vy2 = transform(vx, memberFunc); // does not compile

    }

    flt memberFunc(int x) {
        return 2 * x;
    }

    static flt staticMemberFunc(int x) {
        return 2 * x;
    }
};
```

Comment: `std::bind(&Test::memberFunc, this, std::placeholders::_1)` for the second parameter to the second call would seem a nice fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a lambda to bind the object pointer:

```
auto vy2 = transform(vx, [this](int x){return this->memberFunc(x);});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

1. use `std::bind()` to give you a functor which you can pass in
2. use a lambda function to do the same as 1.